# Change from Jade template to ejs for MEAN Stack

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack

I am currently new to use MEAN stack with the following packages: https://github.com/linnovate/mean. However, after I had created the project and found that Jade is their default template engine.

Are there any good ways to convert those jade template to ejs with changing related settings in Express?

Thank you.

Comment: Just to be strait, you found a library you want to try, but you feel you have to reformat their code before you'll try using it?  (ie: from Jade format to EJS format)  Or, do you just want the new code you write to be under EJS template?

Comment: It would be better if the provided code has options for me to generate clean ejs template without manually change by myself

Comment: Yep! So ask the contributors where to enter a feature request, and how to get started.  (even if you do it yourself, be sure to create some kind of feature request so you can get some level of help from the contributors)

Comment: Not sure about ejs but you may get some ideas from  - http://www.100percentjs.com/replacing-jade-with-hogan-in-an-express-js-app-the-mean-stack/

Answer (score 1):

Inside app.js change:

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
```

to

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

then

1. Open your jade-based page on chrome browser.
2. Open the mouse context-menu on browser and select "inspect element".
3. Select the html tag and copy it as HTML.
4. Paste that HTML on your favorite HTML editor or any code editor.
5. Adjust some tags to fit to 'ejs'.  For example, change 'block body' to '<%- body%>   or   change any data string to a data variable like {{data}} or & quot; to " ' ".
6. save the files with ejs instead of jade.

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');// here you set EJS
```

Comment: Your answer should contain an explanation of your code and a description how it solves the problem.