# Html template with Angular

Tags: angularjs, express, mean-stack

How to use Html template instead of Jade in Angular Application.

**layout.html:**

```
<body>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
<h1>Hello!! whats up from layout</h1>
</body>
```

**index.html:**

```
{% extends 'includes/layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
<section> <h1>hello</h1></section>
{% endblock %}
```

**Server.js**

```
app.set('views',__dirname + '/server/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine','html');

app.get('*',function(req,res){
  res.render('index');
});
```

But i am not getting output as expected, below is the snap of what i am getting in the browser.

```
{% extends 'includes/layout.html' %} {% block content %}
hello

{% endblock %}
```

I don't understand what i am missing.

Comment: confused... you said you want to use "pure html" with angular, and yet, that's not what you have... weird..

Comment: pure html in the sense of html view engine

Comment: So, to clarify, angularjs has nothing to do with this, you're having trouble getting your view engine to render the view.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're not utilizing the proper view engine. See [this article](http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/05/31/how-to-use-ejs-in-express/) by Rod Dodson. The crucial line is:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

You have:

```
app.set('view engine','html');
```

This means express is simply rendering your EJS templates as raw HTML. Make sure Express understands which view engine you want to use, and you should be set.

Comment: nope..i tried that..its not working. the article using .ejs files..while i have .html files

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want them to remain .html files? If they are EJS templates they should likely use the .ejs extension, otherwise the view engine may behave strangely.

Comment: yeah actually i have a requirement of working with .html files only I want to try the same approach that mean.io guys are using.. .html files with mean stack application

Comment: Hmm... I'm too familiar with the Mean documentation, but I wasn't able to find any mention of EJS in there specifically. [This SO question may be of use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998129/change-from-jade-template-to-ejs-for-mean-stack) - my tact here is give everything a go and then take what works and assess. Changing your extension won't break anything - give it a shot and see if that gets you close.

Answer (score 0):

I have a nice little working MEAN stack  [application](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-todo-app/), and i believe it can be a good base for you to set up express/node app with AngularJS HTML templates.

Even if your configured view engine  in **app.js**(server.js or whatever name you call it) might be jade or EJS, Expressjs is quite flexible,you can still serve the HTML partials using AngualrJS routes.

So my base index.html looks something like this:

NOTE: there are ways to efficiently load JS files, but since it's a small To-Do App. so i am not going for it.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="app">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>MEAN To Do Application </title>

    <link href="vendor/flat-ui/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="vendor/flat-ui/css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

    </head>
    <body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <div ng-include="'app/header.tpl.html'"></div>
    <div ng-view class="container-fluid"></div>

    <script src="vendor/flat-ui/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/flat-ui/js/vendor/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/flat-ui/js/vendor/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/flat-ui/js/vendor/video.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/flat-ui/js/flat-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/angular-full/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-full/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/angular-full/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script>
    <script src="common/socketservice.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>  
    <script src="app/meetups/meetups.js"></script>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Then here comes by Angular routes config([refer](https://github.com/narendrasoni1989/mean-todo-app/blob/master/client/src/app/meetups/meetups.js)):

```
angular.module('meetups',['ngResource'],['$routeProvider',function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/',{
        templateUrl: 'app/meetups/list.tpl.html',
        controller: 'MeetupsController'
    })
    .when('/create',{
        templateUrl : 'app/meetups/create.tpl.html',
        controller: 'MeetupsController'
    })
    .when('/:id',{
        templateUrl: 'app/meetups/details.tpl.html',
        controller: 'MeetupsController'
    })
    .when('/:id/edit',{
        templateUrl: 'app/meetups/edit.tpl.html',
        controller: 'MeetupsController'
    })
    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'})
    ;
}]);
```

I hope i answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a clientside solution. Just FYI.

1. You may set any other character for angular's interpolate symbol:

   ```
   app.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
       $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
   });
   ```

(but it's may hurt - ide with angular support didn't recognize your symbol)

2. The best practice of binding - is use ngBind whenever it's possible (instead of {{ }} expresions):

   ```
   <span ng-bind="myVal"></span>
   ```

> It is preferable to use ngBind instead of {{ expression }} if a template is momentarily displayed by the browser in its raw state before Angular compiles it. Since ngBind is an element attribute, it makes the bindings invisible to the user while the page is loading.
>   (from [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind))

instead of

```
    <span>{{myVal}}</span>
```